# Round corners of buttons and colour change for android button

Tags: android-xml

I want to following features in buttons in android button:

1. Buttons should change colours when clicked
2. Some specific buttons have features like the background color of button should remain changed until we press another button.

Answer (score 1):

**For rounded corners you can use below code :**

```
 @drawable/rounderd_corner.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/YOUR_COLOR" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
```

**And For selector Buttons use below @drawable/select_button_color.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/YOUR_COLOR" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
```

**And Change background resource when button is clicked**

Answer (score 1):

**For circular and for changing color when selected/not-selected button you can use following code snippet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And you problem will be **solved**, hope it helps.